# Extract Sub string using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have a column called path like below. I want to extract the sub strings 'AMERICANS','APAC','EAME' from each row. I am hence looking for a Regex which can do this for me. I am not very good at Regex. Can anyone please help me with this ?
I need a Java Regex

Path

```
F:\Email Alias\AMERICIANS\Americas - Team
F:\Email Alias\AMERICIANS\Americas - Territory
F:\Email Alias\AMERICIANS\Americas- Market
F:\Email Alias\APAC\APAC - Market
F:\Email Alias\EAME\EAME - Team
```

Required:

```
AMERICANS
AMERICIANS
AMERICIANS
APAC
EAME
```

Thank You.

Comment: Regular expressions return true or false... you will have to split your string at every "/" and chop that into an array. You have provided a minimum of detail and that is why I keep my answer this short - I am not willing to do more work than you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would match the strings you want.

```
[^\\]+(?=\\[^\\]*$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kS1eO8/2)

i think you need to escape the backslash one more time in qregularexpression.

**Regular Expression:**

```
[^\\]+                   any character except: '\\' (1 or more
                         times)
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  \\                       '\'
  [^\\]*                   any character except: '\\' (0 or more
                           times)
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                           the string
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: FYI, it appears the regex flavor is Java, not QRegularExpression. I've retagged it, but your double-escaping advice still applies.